# Parsing contact info from a .pst (outlook) file

Tags: python, csv, email, outlook

I have .pst (outlook) file, which contains old emails and email contacts (around 3980 of them), which I'd like to export to a machine readable format.

Outlook 2016 already has an option to export the contacts to a .csv file, but after the export operation is performed, one can see, that the file is not structured properly. The "Notes" field may contain a messagge, which might contain multiple new line characters. This, in turn, breaks the .csv format, since every entry should start with the value of the first contact field (but in these cases, the lines represent the successive content of the mentioned "Notes" field). When the "Notes" field is finished, the next line usually contains the rest of the values of the entry.

Example csv output:

```
"Title","First Name",... <- header field values of the exported .csv
"","John","","Travolta","","ValueX","","","ValueY",,,"ValueZ",... <- start of the contact entry
www.link1.com           <- start of the "Notes" field (same contact)
..................      <- "Notes" field continued (same contact)
www.link2.com           <- "Notes" field continued (same contact)
...................     <- "Notes" field continued (same contact)
"asd","asdas","asdasd","asdasd"             <- rest of the contact fields (same contact)
"","Nicolas","Cage","","","ValueX","","","ValueY",,,"ValueZ",... <- 2nd contact (in one line)
```

I'd like to fix the formatting of the exported file, so the "Notes" field would not stretch across multiple lines and each contact would be represented in the file as a single line.

I think I have two options here:

- write a script (python), which goes over the lines and fixes the formatting (I'd like to avoid doing this, since the script might overlook something).
- find an API for parsing .pst files and try to serialize the contacts in the suitable format (by specifying how to serialize the "Notes" field manually).

Does anybody know, if I'm overlooking something and if this could be solved in an easier way?

Kind regards.

**EDIT:** I'm talking about [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/importing-csv-with-line-breaks/a989987f-e12f-43f9-8ea5-79543012457e?auth=1) issue.

Comment: CSV files are allowed newlines in cells. Try loading it into Excel, you should see it is correctly displayed.

Comment: I've added a link to the OP, where someone dealt with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The file exported from Outlook is not broken although it may appear to look like it is. In effect, a newline character inside quotes is considered part of the cell. So if cells have newlines, it would mean a single "row" will be be loaded from many lines in the file.

For example for a CSV say you have four cells in one row, `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`. This would look like:

```
a,b,c,d
```

Now change `c` to be `c1\nc2`, i.e. it has a newline in it:

```
a,b,"c1
c2",d
```

The cell is now quoted and appears on multiple lines. The standard Python CSV library will be able to correctly parse this, including a standard Outlook exported CSV contact file.

The following displays a name and home address from each contact given a standard contacts CSV file exported from Outlook:

```
import csv

with open('contacts.csv', 'r', newline='') as f_contacts:
    csv_contacts = csv.DictReader(f_contacts)

    for contact in csv_contacts:
        print(contact['First Name'], contact['Last Name'])
        print("{}{}{}".format(contact['Home Street'], contact['Home Street 2'], contact['Home Street 3']).replace('\n\n','\n'))
        print()
```

This assumes you are using Python 3.x and was tested using a CSV file exported directly from Outlook.